# noticed a Strange thing in previous pages on chrome history

Tags: android

I saw this com.google.android.trichromelibrary_495106133
suddenly on my phon in the history in menu on Chrome.
What is it?

Comment: you may read [trichromelibrary](https://yoodley.com/trichromelibrary/)

Answer (score 0):

In old Android versions, Chrome App was used by WebView for rendering web pages in apps, but in Android 10, Google started using a new implementation called “Trichrome.”

**Here’s the statement from a Google engineer:
“Chrome is no longer used as a WebView implementation in Q+. We’ve moved to a new model for sharing common code between Chrome and WebView (called “Trichrome”), which gives the same benefits of reduced download and install size while having fewer weird special cases and bugs.”**

Please check [link](https://yoodley.com/trichromelibrary/) for more information